# Creating a ToDoList, isDone function

Tags: javascript, boolean

I need to create a isDone for my ToDoList and it should return true or false if it's done or not. But if the isDone date is set it should throw an Error since it should be a "read-only". I was thinking something like:

```
function ToDoItem(isDone) {
    let _isDone;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'isDone', {
        get: function() {
            return _isDone;
        }
    });
}
```

But how do I continue so the value returned is true or false?

In my finishedDate I did this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'finishedDate', {
    get: function() {
      return _finishedDate;
    },
    set: function(finishedDate) {
      if (finishedDate !== undefined && Object.prototype.toString.call(finishedDate) !== '[object Date]') {
        throw new TypeError('invalid date');
      }
        _finishedDate = finishedDate;

    }
});
```

Comment: How do you determine if it's done or not?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I put in an edit where I entered my code for finishedDate also

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a functional function for what you want is it? I would have guess something simple like the following philosophy

```
function isDone(item) {
    return todoList.getItem(item).status;
}
```

Comment: I think I need to use something like `function compareTime(time1, time2) {`
`return new Date(time1) > new Date(time2);`
`}`. Because here it will return true if time1 is later than time2? But how do I change this so I can use getters?

Comment: What i would done is to have a "class" todoList so i can initialize at first. Then for each item to have some standard configuration as status, time etc. So if you have that in every object by getting the item you have all the info you want to just check the time, status or whatever else you want.

Comment: Well if I use `Object.defineProperty(this, 'isDone', {` 
`get: function(dueDate, finishedDate) {`
`return new Date(dueDate) > new Date(finishedDate);`
`}`
`});`. It tests okay on return false but not that it should return true, why is that?